# Progress bar while loading the page with javascript (Without JQuery)

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game and I need a progress bar to show the player the percentage of load that is missing before the content is displayed, the problem is that I have not managed to find a way to achieve this with just javascript (without jquery) and those that are found do not show the true time missing, but an estimate like this example:

```
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The bar should not load with a random time, it should be with the time it takes to load the page

I have tried the following, but it is not generating any response:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "index.html");
xhr.send();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log(percentComplete);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var width, id;

function move() {
  width = 10;
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);
}

function frame() {
  if (width >= 100) {
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {
    width++;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = width + '%';
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }
}
move();
```

```css
#myBar {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBar">
  <span id="label"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? This answer only provides code to make a bar fill from 10% to 100% over 0.9 seconds... Nothing about this answer is helpful to OP. I don't think his question was "How do I increase the width of a div every 10 milliseconds", but rather "How do I measure the amount of 'loading' that the page has completed vs the total amount needed."

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the solution has nothing to do with the question